# Running make from Outside the Tree

Tags: directory, makefile

Let's say I have a makefile like the following:

```
CXXFLAGS := -I./Include

Foo:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o Foo
```

If the user `cd`s into the source tree and runs `make`, everything is fine and dandy.  However, if `make` is invoked from somewhere outside the source tree, the include directory will be incorrect.

Using full paths instead of relative paths works, but that destroys the portability of the makefile.

Should I just rely on users invoking `make` "properly?"  Or is there an easy way to get around this?

Comment: Suppose there are two `Include` directories. Somehow the user must tell Make which one to use. Which way would you prefer?

Comment: @Beta I'm afraid I don't follow.  Where is the other `Include` dir?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Do you want Make to search the whole tree and use the first `Include/` it finds? Or use the one in the same dir as the makefile (with e.g. Ise Wisteria's solution)? Or should the use specify the path in the command line, or in an environmental variable, or a parameter file, or how? What *defines* the `Include/` you want Make to use?

Comment: @Beta Presumably the include directory is in the same directory as the makefile, but the real issue is how to use a relative path as if it were relative to the makefile rather than the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have `CXXFLAGS` be `-Isome_dir/Include`
when the `make` is invoked as
`make -f some_dir/Makefile`,
[MAKEFILE_LIST](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0040r_007b_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029_007d-537)
might meet the purpose.

For example:

```
MAKEFILE_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
CXXFLAGS := -I$(MAKEFILE_DIR)Include
```

If your `make`'s version is 3.80 or lower, `lastword` might not work.

In that case,
`$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))` will work instead.

**EDIT:** This answer is for GNU-make.

Comment: I'm assuming this is specific to GNU make?

Comment: @Maxpm: Oh, sorry, yes, this answer is for GNU-make.

Comment: @Maxpm: so which version of Make do you use?

Comment: @Beta GNU, but I'd like to keep it portable for as long as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-C` flag.

```
make -C my_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You could present your users a compile command that looks like `(cd /to/proper/directory && make -k)`